# Getting data attribute value in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I am adding data attribute in td something like this :

```
   <td style="text-align:center;padding: 3px 0;data-id:2;data-env:PL1;"><img  src="/VendorFeedDevUI/Content/green.png" style="width:25px" alt="Green"><div>21 Dec 14<br>23:55:00</div></td>
```

When I want to retrieve the same attribute in Jquery I am using below code :

```
  $(".gradienttable tr td").click(function () {
        showRefreshControl();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var env = $(this).data('env')
       });
```

I am trying to use both ways to get data attributes but both are returning undefined.
 Also I am getting td object for `$(this)` so that is not an issue.
 So what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That's not a `data` attribute in your HTML, it's a CSS property which does not exist.

Comment: there is 'data-id' and 'data-env'

Comment: @user3013365 No, they are CSS properties as you write it, btw, invalid ones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using it the wrong way:

```
 <td style="text-align:center;padding: 3px 0;" data-id="2" data-env="PL1">...</td>
```

You add the data attributes to your styles, you have to place it outside the style attribute.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <td style="text-align:center;padding: 3px 0;" data-id="2" data-env="PL1"><!-- ... --></td>
```

That's how you set attributes, not within your style.

You can then pick it up like you have done here:

```
  $(".gradienttable tr td").click(function () {
        showRefreshControl();
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `data` attribute in your HTML, it's a CSS property which does not exist. Change your HTML to actually use the correct attributes then your code should work:

```
<td style="text-align: center; padding: 3px 0;" data-id="2" data-env="PL1">
   <img src="/VendorFeedDevUI/Content/green.png" style="width:25px" alt="Green" />
   <div>21 Dec 14<br>23:55:00</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td style="text-align:center;padding: 3px 0;" data-id = "2" data-env = "PL1">
```